# Machine Learning strategy needed

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a group of 20 yes/no/na questions that my company uses to assess whether or not to bid for an opportunity. To date, we have filled out the questionnaire 634 times.

The current algorithm simply divides yes / (yes + no) and a score over 50% recommends that we pursue the opportunity. n/a answers are disregarded.

We have tracked win/loss data on all of the pursuits, so I have a labeled dataset and I'm considering a supervised machine learning algorithm to replace our crude yes/no calculation.

I'm looking for a suggested method of supervised machine learning in Python (I'm most familar with SKLearn). Decision Tree Classifier?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Naive Bayes Classifiers, Decision Trees, or Artificial Neural Networks (I personally recommend this).

Comment: Encrypt the data and attach it here. You will be able to get a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You have 20 y/n answers as features. Let yes be 1 and no be 0. So there are 20 binary features.

You also have target variable (win/loss) data. Let win be 1 and loss be 0. You can use an SVM/ NN right away. In my experience SVM and logistic regression give similar accuracies.

But if you are looking to explain each feature's contribution in shaping the decision, you should use naive-bayes or Decision Trees

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know who is saying yeses and nos, so if you have 10 experts answering those 20 questions with yes/no/na, you have 10x20x3 states or binary features where every expert has 60 features.

Besides you can use features from the project itself like if the project is from oil industry or mining or manufacturing, etc. Some experts might be better in prediction in one industry over the others.

For classification, you can try random forests from sklearn.

Note that instead of classification (labelling if the project was pursued or disregarded) you can change the problem into a regression task by labelling the samples with the amount of profit or loss the company achieved from either pursuing (- or +) or disregarding (0) the project.

Hope this helps.